# Проблема с параллельной работой потоков с++

Tags: c++

Есть код, который по какой-то причине ничего не возвращает. Я пытался сделать, чтобы функции выполнялись параллельно. Почему так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Tread {
public:
    //Оба потока используют генерацию каких-либо чисел и вывод на экран текущей строки
    //Возвращает случайное от значение от min до max
    unsigned getRandom(unsigned min, unsigned max) {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        return min + rand()%(max-min+1);
    }

    void operator()(string &text, mutex &mx) {
        int i = 0;
        while (true){
        mx.lock();
        cout << text << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        mx.unlock();
        }
    }
};

class Append : protected Tread {
public:
        void operator()(string &text, mutex &mx) {
            while(true) {
                //Пусть добавляется от 1 до 10 символов
                mx.lock();
                unsigned countRandomSymbols = getRandom(1, 3);
                for (int i = 0; i < countRandomSymbols; i++) {
                    //Коды ASCII от 97 до 122
                    int randomSymbol = getRandom(97, 122);
                    text.push_back(char(randomSymbol));
                }
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
                mx.unlock();
            }
        }
};

class Delete : protected Tread {
public:
    void operator()(string &text, mutex &mx) {
        while (true) {
            mx.lock();
            //Случайная позиция будущего удаленного элемента
            unsigned deletingNumber = getRandom(1, text.length());
            text.erase(deletingNumber, 1);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            mx.unlock();
        }
    }
};


int main(){

    mutex mx;
    string text = "Groovy Haskell Scala";
    Tread main;
    Append app;
    Delete del;

    thread tr1(main, ref(text), ref(mx));
    thread tr2(del, ref(text), ref(mx));
    thread tr3(app, ref(text), ref(mx));

    tr3.detach();
    tr2.detach();
    tr1.detach();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что при использовании потоков каждый обязан прострелить себе ногу посредством `detach`.

Comment: Вообще-то вы даже не проверяли перед `detach`, успел ли поток запуститься (joinable); во-вторых - тут же заканчиваете программу - потоки вообще ничего не успевают сделать, как вы уже говорите, что все, умрите, несчастные... :)

Comment: @Harry А поток сразу joinable после такого конструктора.

Comment: @VTT Охотно поверю; я предпочитаю `async`. Но в любом случае убиение программы непосредственно после запуска потоков представляется мне, как бы это сказать... опрометчивым.

Comment: Что такое "код, который ничего не возвращает"? Что вы вообще имеете в виду под "не возвращает"? Как в С++ код может что-то "возвращать"? О чем речь вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Программа завершается по завершении функции `main`, Вам нужно изменить код, чтобы

- Все потоки в конце `main` вызывали `join`
- Сами потоки были не бесконечны, т.е. они могут выполнять работу бесконечно, но проверяя какой-то флаг, который будет кто-то выставлять. По выставлении этого флага, потоки будут завершаться и произойдёт выход из `main`. Ну или просто ограничить количество итерации в каждом потоке, чтобы они завершились без внешнего воздействия. В противном случае, программа будет работать бесконечно.